# Table View "Delete"(on Swipe) coming below indexing

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

[image]

As In the Given Image, I am trying to delete a table view row by swipe on table view cell. But the problem is that the delete button is coming below the indexes but my requirement is to show it over the index. Can you suggest any method to do this??

Comment: This is a bug in iOS 7. It is fixed in iOS 8.

Comment: What about just hide the index when the delete option is shown?